# Camera Multiple Image Capture in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    if ([multipleCapture isOn])
    {
        images=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        currentDate=[NSDate date];
        myString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
        customText=imagetext.text;
        saveImage.dateTime=myString;
        saveImage.imageName=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        saveImage.customText=customText;
        [imageArray addObject:saveImage];
        [imageArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        if ([imageArray count] == 1) 
        {
           UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(images.size);
           myString=[[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"dateTime"];
          [images drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, images.size.width, images.size.height)];
          NSDictionary* attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFontboldSystemFontOfSize:75],NSStrokeColorAttributeName :[UIColor blackColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor],NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @-2.0};
          [myString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(120,70)withAttributes:attributes];
          [customText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(870, 70)withAttributes:attributes];
          newImage= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
          UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage,self,@selector(savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        }
    }
}
```

/* I worked on this code. The issue is when I try to make multiple shot it shows "Received   Memory Warning" and my app got crashed.
    In this I tried to count the images,at the same time It counts "Camera not ready mode" also  So that my taken images saved multiple times.
    How can I solve this issue ? */

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
int counter;
NSMutableArray * imageArray;

-(void)takePicture
 {
       counter=0;
       UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];
}

 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
UIImage *image= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

[imageArray addObject:image];
counter++;  
if (counter<PhotoCount)
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:NO];
    [imagePicker release];
}
else
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

}
```

`PhotoCount` is the number of photos you want to take.

Comment: /* I am asking about saving the images simultaneously when we capture multiple images. At that time we don't know how many images we gonna take? Also images should have exact image taken time on the images.saving process works on background mode also. Can u help me */