# How do I make custom camera like Cam Scanner in iOS(exactly similar to the CamScanner app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

Can anyone tell me about Cam Scanner? How to implement that in my app. I have searched a lot about this. Can anyone suggest me any link or SDKs so that I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Many Library Are available In GitHub Site For cam Scanner Application Same as [this one is best cam scanner application to solve your issue](https://github.com/mukyasa/MMCamScanner)

Comment: thanks for replaying.i saw this example but my requirement is not only cropping the image. i have to capture multiple image from camera and concatenate all the images into pdf.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generating-pdf-documents--mobile-11265

Comment: yes i'm following some tutorial for the pdf conversation.but i have struck with the multiple capture image on single button.user can click number of pics it has to show some where.

Comment: create your custom camera in You can set how many image you want after try to create pdf file

Comment: Please give some example for the multiple image capture on single button

Comment: i can put first cam scanner link in used custom camera are so you try to add one or more view in this custom camera

Comment: i'm following this code for multiple image capture http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268421/camera-multiple-image-capture-in-ios

Comment: here i have to set the count and i don't want set the count that user can decide.

Comment: you can set two counter variable first is counter and second is photo count and user can enter count this are store in photo count variable after work it